# How to catch the close event on packaged app (google chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, events, tabs

I am developing a packaged app for Google Chrome.

Right now this app opens on a tab, I want to do an action when the user closes my app.

But I was not able to do this so far :

- I tried to listen to unload event but didn't work.
- I tried the chrome.tabs.addListener (or something like that) but the only problem is that this works only if any other tab on that instance of chrome closes.

  But if I close my application which has the function that handles the event; the event is not fired.

Does anyone know what I need to do to catch the close event?

Comment: There is a discussion about this here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130465
I wonder how to destroy sockets used by the App...